# Use awk to pattern matching

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have a file hoge.txt like this:

```
case $1 in
[ $input = "q" ] && exit
if [ -s $filename ]    
if [ ! -f $1 -o -f $2 ]
echo $list
rm -f ${BKDIR}
BKDIR=/${HOME}/backup
```

And I want to find all alphabetic variables, exclude every parameters like "$1" and output to a new file like this:

```
$input
$filename
$list
```

The best i can do now is

```
cat hoge.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="$/[a-zA-Z]/"){print $i} } }'
```

But it doesn't return any results.

Comment: Only lower-case words?

Comment: Both upper-case and lower-case. I want to exclude anything not purely alphabatic: $HOME is ok but ${HOME} will be excluded.

Comment: change your if condition to `if($i~/^\$[a-zA-Z]+$/)` ... but what about variables like `${BKDIR}`? and what about `HOME` in `BKDIR=/${HOME}/backup`?

Comment: @shift-e: exactly my question as Sundeep's above

Comment: @shift-e: If you are using in `bash` context, the variables `$HOME` and `${HOME}` literally mean the same. Not sure why you want to exclude the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Awk` for such a trivial example, just use extended regular expressions support using the `-E` flag and print only the matching word using `-o`

```
grep -Eo '\$[a-zA-Z]+' file
```

produces

```
$input
$filename
$list
```

and write to a new file using the re-direction(`>`) operator

```
grep -Eo '\$[a-zA-Z]+' file > variablesList
```

(or) saving two key strokes (suggested in comments below) with enabling the case insensitive flag with `-i`

```
grep -iEo '\$[a-z]+' file
```

Comment: This is possible, too: `grep -iEo '\$[A-Z]+' file`

Comment: @Cyrus: Yup saving two key strokes in the end ;) (`i`  newly added and `a-z` removed)